# Mysql Movie/Tags select query

Tags: mysql

So, I have a database with 3 tables with the relevant columns:

1. tags : TID, tag_name
2. movies : MID, movie_title
3. tags_to_movies : movie_ID, tag_ID

How do I select the movies that have at least the tags I want.

So, if I have a movie1 with tags (1,2,3) and movie2 with (1,4) when I select by TID 1 I get movie1 and movie2 as a result, but when I query for TID (1,2) I only get movie1.

I looked around a bit on the web already and I don't think I found the solution (or didn't try hard enough).

Comment: Probably because your where clause is and tid=1 and tid=2 which would only succeed for Movie 1.  Try select movie_title from movies m, tags t, tags_to_movies c where m.mid = c.movie_id and c.tag_id in (my select list here - like "c.tag_id in (1, 2)")

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.MID, m.movie_title
from movies m
join tags_to_movies tm on tm.movie_id = m.mid
join tags t on tm.tag_id = t.tid
where t.tid in (1,4)
group by m.MID, m.movie_title
having count(distinct t.tid) = 2
```

`having count(distinct t.tid) = 2` depends on the number of tags you have. For 3 tags use `having count(distinct t.tid) = 3`.

Comment: I had something slightly different using GROUP BY and HAVING as well, but this one works well. Thank you very much.